# There are session hosts not sending data to the expected Log Analytics workspace - Azure virtual Desktop

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have enabled Diagnostic settings on AVD `Host Pool` and `Workspace`. But When I navigate to `Host Pool > Monitoring > Insights`   I see below error message:

`There are session hosts not sending data to the expected Log Analytics workspace. Number of session hosts needing attention: 1`

[image]

What is missing?